# 3D Thumbnail Hover Effects

Tags: javascript, html, css, effect

Im trying to use [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DHoverEffects/) effect.
You can download it [here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DHoverEffects/3DHoverEffects.zip).

My problem is that the images I'm trying to insert on it don't have a fixed size. I want to use max-width and max-height.

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?  External links are subject to change, so it'll help you and the next person with your issue.

Comment: Can you include any code you have tried that should be working?